# WhatsApp - Some contact names changed to "Number LastName"

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

I have installed WhatsApp and WhatsApp Business on the same phone. While installing, I did not give contact permission for WhatsApp Business. Later I added the permission.

Now, when I check WhatsApp, I see most of the contacts changed to "Number LastName".
For example, the Name "Rauf Mohd" with number "+91123456789" is now showing in WhatsApp as "+91123456789 Mohd". So when I search "Rauf", I could not get it.

I have tried the below.

1. I have un-linked the contact and then re-linked. It works well. But I have to do one by one.
2. I have "Refresh"ed the contacts. But no change.
3. I have uninstalled and re-installed both apps. But no change.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: WhatsApp uses shared Contacts Provider to retrieve the contact name. This means that the issue is possibly on the Contacts app itself.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes. I checked the contacts app. There it shows "Number LastName". But I did not change anything in the contact app. Anyway, how can I fix this ?

Comment: As @AndrewT. said WhatsApp has no hand in this. Maybe you installed any app or logged into a new Google account? Go to settings and see which all apps have the contact permission